# How to make select queries repeatedly with php?

Tags: php, mysql

Basically what I need is to make queries that depend on the values ​​of a text file that I'm reading.
This is the code that I have.

```
   $con = mysqli_connect($host,$name,$pass,$db);

   $file = fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

   while(!feof($file))
   {  
        $codigo = fgets($file);
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT column FROM table WHERE column='". $codigo."'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        echo $row;
   }
   fclose($file);
   mysqli_close($con);
```

But I can´t get that I want. I have some values in my text file but when I excecute this I only get the query of the last value of my text file.

Any suggestion?

If I add this line inside the while:

```
echo $codigo . "<br>";
```

All the content of my text file are printed, so I think the problem is in the result variable. All the values of the text file return a null value when I make the query except the last.

Comment: what are the contents of your text file ?

Comment: `while ($codigo = fgets($file)) { var_dump($codigo); }` ... This will tell you what's being read from the file.  Maybe your text file has repeats of the same data..

Comment: the content of the file are code like:
HJ5435
654JLL
54GFDH one by line

Comment: All the content are strings, could this be the error?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
print_r($row);
```

or

```
echo $row["column"];
```

instead of

```
echo $row;
```

Otherwise you will always have "Array" returned.

Comment: Thanks but I get the same result

Comment: Does always only one data row match one query?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is someting stupid, when I read a file line by line, PHP also read the newline (\n) so when I make a query the where condition never is true.
A quick solution is make a substring.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is this line:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

And that's why you only see the last result. You keep overwriting that value with the new result. Instead of rewriting the string, keep adding to the array, then after the loop var_dump or print_r the array.

```
$row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

It also might help you to use mysqli in an object-oriented fashion, the way it was designed:

```
$result = $con->query($query);
```